# JSTL c:if does not recognize String inside ${} and causes EL syntax error

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

Why are the "POST" and "submit" parts of this code highlighted in a different color in my IDE?

[image]

Also the syntax highlighter here doesn't highlight them in same color.

```
<c:if test="${"POST".equalsIgnoreCase(pageContext.request.method) && pageContext.request.getParameter("submit") !=null}">

</c:if>
```

Does that mean that EL does not recognize the string and so gives me an EL syntax error?

How can I solve this?

Comment: i updated changes. copy code and paste it, and if you find any error, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `<c:if>`, your `test` attribute is a also a string, which is set with double quotes, and you also have `"POST"` as string literal which you are using inside string as string with double quotes. So compiler understands that as end of `<c:if test>` condition. In effects, you end up having a `<c:if test="${">` instead of the intended one.

Replace the double quotes inside the `test` attribute with single quotes like this:

```
<c:if test="${'POST'.equalsIgnoreCase(pageContext.request.method) && pageContext.request.getParameter('submit') != null}">

</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a backslash character to escape the double quotes like this:

```
<c:if test="${\"POST\".equalsIgnoreCase(pageContext.request.method)  && pageContext.request.getParameter(\"submit\") !=null}">
</c:if>
```